# Windows Service File I/O Exception

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, windows-services

I am trying to write a Windows service on a PC running 64-bit Windows using Visual Studio 2008.  In this service, I am trying to read a a control file from an external drive located on a different machine on the same LAN.  The path to the file from the reading machine will be via a mapped network drive...( T:).   I am using a TextFieldParser from Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO class to read the file at T:\filename.  I'm getting a file not found exception, however, the path to the drive works perfectly if I copy and paste it into Windows Explorer from the same machine.

Anyone know if there are any issues connecting in this manner and/or what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure that the account under which the service runs has a drive mapping to `T:`, or, better, try using a UNC path (e.g. \\server1\someshare\filename). And you will still need to make sure that the account has access to the file. Try to use an account with its access rights limited to only what it needs, so not the Administrator account.